# How can i ensure that a task is finished before cron starts a new one

Tags: cron

I have a cron script that runs every 5 minutes to fetch data from a remote system and it works as expected. My issue is that sometimes the task takes longer then 5 minutes which means i have a new task started before the old one finishes. So i am wondering if i can check and if so how if the old job is still running before i start a new one.
I would guess basic id would be to go create a textfile, and have a value in it, like true or false and then before i run it check if its true or false, if false update to true and run, if false terminate and wait till next run

Comment: There are some other answers to your question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150778/prevent-a-second-instance-of-my-software-from-starting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put any value in the file. An empty file will do. Just check if the file exists. If the file exists, then exit the script. Else create the file, fetch data, and delete the file when all the data fetch is done.

## Sample Code

The script below will exit if another instance of it is running. This is done by creating a temporary "lock file" which only exists while the script is running.

The first part of the script checks if the lock file exist, and stops if the lock file exists without doing anything else.

The second part of the script does all the work.

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCK="/home/$USER/bin/fetch.lock"
if [ -f "$LOCK" ]; then
        echo "Another instance of $0 is running, exiting..."
        exit 1
fi

touch $LOCK  # Creates the file
trap "rm $LOCK" EXIT    
echo "Fetch data"
sleep 1m     # wait for 1 minute for testing
echo "Done fetching data"
```

Note, the trap command will remove the lock file if the script is interrupted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or when the script ends normally.

This sample script does not fetch any data. It just displays the words "fetch data", waits for a minute, and then displays "Done fetching data". To make it do the real work, **replace the following lines with your own lines**:

```
echo "Fetch data"
sleep 1m     # wait for 1 minute for testing
echo "Done fetching data"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'd add `trap EXIT rm "$lock"` just after `touch "$lock"` in case the user interrupts the long running transfer (`sleep 1m`) with `^C` and leaves the "`$lock`" file behind.

Comment: @waltinator Thanks for pointing me to the the `trap` command. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Quick question , should i use trap EXIT rm "$Lock" or the trap "rm $LOCK" EXIT

Comment: @AP_AP Use the one in the answer. Otherwise you will get a syntax error.